# How to produce several batches of different size for the same data using Rx.NET?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an observable sequence `IObservable<int>` and I would like to convert it to `IObservable<IList<int>>` while preserving the following requirements:

- The final observable is a sequence of batches, but there are two kinds of them - **A** and **B**, the **A** batches contain 1000 items each, where as the **B** batches contain 400 items each.
- Each number from the original sequence must be batched twice - once in some **A** batch and another time in some **B** batch
- The processing should be on the fly and the two kinds of batches should be produced in parallel. I.e. a solution where first all the **A** batches are produced and then all the **B** batches is not acceptable.

I can easily produce batches of one kind using the `Buffer` operator, but I have no idea how to produce the two batches on the same data.

**EDIT**

Here is a trivial code to generate just one kind of a batch.

```
IObservable<int> source = GetSource(...);
await source
    .Buffer(1000)
    .Select(batch => Observable.FromAsync(() => ProcessBatchAsync(batch)))
    .Merge(MaxConcurrentBatches)
    .DefaultIfEmpty();
...

private async Task<Unit> ProcessBatchAsync(IList<int> batch)
{
   ...
   return Unit.Default;
}
```

What I want to have is:

- either an Observable of two items, where each item is another observable of the batches of just one kind. That master observable should be complete when the batch observables are.
- a single Observable which produces both kinds of batches. Then I need to switch different operators based on the kind of the monad.

**EDIT2**

I need to elaborate the constraint. The original observable sits on top of the `SqlReader` object and subscribing to it twice means the reader is created twice and the database access is doubled. I need only one subscription.

**EDIT3**

For the example data we can use `Observable.Range(0,10000)`. Given that sequence I need to have the following batches in any order:

```
[0..1000), [0..400), [1000..2000),[400..800),[2000..3000),[800..1200),[3000..4000),[1200..1600) ... [9000..10000) ... [9600..10000)
```

Or you can use the range [0..100) with batches of 10 and 4 numbers. It does not really matter, because the solution should not depend on the batch sizes nor on the number of batch types.

It should be applicable to having 3 batches of 10, 4 and 6 numbers, for instance. Or any other combination.

**EDIT4**

I think I have confused people with my constraints. When I say "interleaved" I do not mean the batch types must rotate strictly. It is just how I am trying to explain that batches of different types must be produced concurrently. Given 3 batch types A,B and C it is possible that two batches of type A are produced one after another occasionally. It is unacceptable, however, if first all the batches of type A, then all the batches of type B and then all the batches of type C.

Comment: So you want 2 subscribers to the list with different batch sizes?

Comment: Please show how you can "easily produce batches of one kind using the `Buffer` operator" and provide us with sample input data and the expected output. I might be thick, but I really do understand your explanation.

Comment: @mark - Don't forget to `@` notify - it was lucky I just happened to check back here.

Comment: @mark - You haven't got the "provide us with sample input data and the expected output" in the question yet.

Comment: @Enigmativity - see EDIT3. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think this produces what you need:

```
var query =
    Observable
        .Range(0, 10000)
        .Publish(ns =>
            ns
                .Buffer(1000)
                .Concat(Observable.Repeat(new List<int>() as IList<int>))
                .Zip(ns.Buffer(400), (n1s, n2s) => new [] { n1s, n2s })
                .SelectMany(nns => nns)
                .Where(xs => xs.Any()));
```

It is properly interleaved as per your example output.

If I reduce the numbers down by a factor of 100 then I get this output:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 
0, 1, 2, 3 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 
4, 5, 6, 7 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 
8, 9, 10, 11 
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39 
12, 13, 14, 15 
40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49 
16, 17, 18, 19 
50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59 
20, 21, 22, 23 
60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69 
24, 25, 26, 27 
70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79 
28, 29, 30, 31 
80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89 
32, 33, 34, 35 
90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99 
36, 37, 38, 39 
40, 41, 42, 43 
44, 45, 46, 47 
48, 49, 50, 51 
52, 53, 54, 55 
56, 57, 58, 59 
60, 61, 62, 63 
64, 65, 66, 67 
68, 69, 70, 71 
72, 73, 74, 75 
76, 77, 78, 79 
80, 81, 82, 83 
84, 85, 86, 87 
88, 89, 90, 91 
92, 93, 94, 95 
96, 97, 98, 99
```

If you don't need them strictly interleaved then this is a way to generalize `n` buffers:

```
var buffers = new [] { 1000, 400, 500, 300 };
var source = Observable.Range(0, 10000);
var result = source.Publish(ss => buffers.Select(b => ss.Buffer(b)).Merge());
```

---

As Theo pointed out the `Observable.Repeat` used in the first query has the potential to produce a very large number of objects. If `Observable.Range` is used this doesn't happen, but if `Observable.Interval` is then it's a large issue.

I was lazy and simply didn't try to do the maths to limit the number of fillers required.

It's easy to fix.

```
var total_item_count = 100;
var batch_a_size = 10;
var batch_b_size = 4;

var filler =
    Observable
        .Repeat(
            new List<long>() as IList<long>,
            Math.Abs(total_item_count / batch_a_size - total_item_count / batch_b_size) + 1);

var query =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.01))
        .Take(total_item_count)
        .Publish(ns =>
            ns
                .Buffer(batch_a_size)
                .Concat(filler)
                .Zip(
                    ns
                        .Buffer(batch_b_size)
                        .Concat(filler),
                    (n1s, n2s) => new [] { n1s, n2s })
                .SelectMany(nns => nns)
                .Where(xs => xs.Any()));
```

I get the same output as before, and now it is configurable for each batch size and there is no run away `Repeat`.

Comment: +1 for a creative solution. But can you scale it to N batch types in general? The solution provided by ionoy is more straightforward and can be generalized easily for N batch types.

Comment: @mark - Ionoy's solution doesn't interleave. Does the output not need to interleave?

Comment: I need them to be produced concurrently, in other words I do need them to be interleaved. The reason - different batches are consumed by different consumers concurrently. But are you sure Ionoy's solution does not interleave? Doesn't `Subscribe` method return immediately?  I need to check it.

Comment: @mark - No, Ionoy's solution does not interleave. If we divide the figures by 100 then the first 6 lots of values produced are : `0, 1, 2, 3`, `4, 5, 6, 7`, `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`, `8, 9, 10, 11`, `12, 13, 14, 15`, `10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19`. Definitely not interleaved. Even worse, if the source observable invokes some threading then the results are not even deterministic.

Comment: The `Observable.Repeat` in the first solution worries me. If I am not mistaken, it's going to produce empty lists in a tight loop (massive amount of lists per second).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Very much the case. I've fixed the issue.

Comment: Now it seems to be under control. It is scary though that the Rx allows to create hard-to-notice memory leaks so easily.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following approach

```
var observable = Observable.Range(0, 10000);

Task.Run(() => observable.Buffer(400).Subscribe(buffer => /* process buffer */ ));
Task.Run(() => observable.Buffer(1000).Subscribe(buffer => /* process buffer */ ));
```

Two kinds of batches will be produced in parallel.

Comment: Please, see my EDIT2. Your proposition is not very good for me, since it means I will be doubling the access to the database.

Comment: Use `Publish(...)` to create a single subscription to database with multiple subscribers.

Comment: @ionoy - Please, arrange your comment as an answer with the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates two `IObservable<IList<int>>` sequences.

```
var source = Observable.Range(0,10000)
                       .Publish();

var batchesOf1000 = source.Buffer(1000);
var batchesOf400 = source.Buffer(400);

batchesOf1000.Subscribe(batch => batch.Dump());
batchesOf400.Subscribe(batch => batch.Dump());

var disposable = source.Connect();
```